# create-react-app > error css-loader@1.0.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">= 6.9.0 <7.0.0 || >= 8.9.0"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I'm unable to `npm init react-app my-app` or `npx create-react-app my-app` even if I have `node -v v8.2.1`. My console output:

```
> [1/4]   Resolving packages... [2/4]   Fetching packages... error
> css-loader@1.0.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module.
> Expected version ">= 6.9.0 <7.0.0 || >= 8.9.0". error Found
> incompatible module info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for
> documentation about this command.
```

I tried to remove css-loader or install the last version of the package. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need node version above of 8.9.0 or between 6.9.0 to 7